# Why is an empty string showing up as a find with my regular expression?

Tags: regex

Recently I've been learning Regular Expressions (calling me a beginner would be generous in case you're wondering how skilled I am) in an online Python course I've been taking. I've been using a helpful online simulator to help debug my regular expression filter, and I've run into a problem. My goal is to filter the user names out of the text file

A few lines from the file:

```
76.72.133.93 - carroll1056 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:05 -0700] "POST /morph/optimize/plug-and-play HTTP/2.0" 400 27172
73.162.151.229 - dubuque3528 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:08 -0700] "DELETE /transition/holistic/e-business HTTP/2.0" 301 13923
13.112.8.86 - rau5626 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:09 -0700] "HEAD /ubiquitous/transparent HTTP/1.1" 200 16928
159.253.153.40 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:10 -0700] "POST le-business HTTP/1.0" 504 19845
136.195.158.6 - feeney9464 [21/Jun/2019:15:46:11 -0700] "HEAD /opensource/markets HTTP/2.0" 264 21149
219.194.113.255 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:12 -0700] "PATCH /nextgeneration/niches/mindshare HTTP/1.0" 503 20246
```

The regex I've tried:

```
([a-z]{1,}\d{1,})?(\-)?(?=(\s\[))
```

However, my filter finds something extra, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3hjG.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x28os.png).

Here's my thought process for my regex:

- I want something that precedes the string ' ]' (space included)
- What that something must be is a username of the form abcd...1234...(lower case letters in a row followed by digits in a row) IF AND ONLY IF that is there (hence the '?')
- The other possibility, if there was no username, that could be preceding the ' ]' is just a dash '-' (second screenshot), which is what the filter should find IF AND ONLY IF a dash is there
- In all cases, either a valid user name or a dash (in the correct spot) is there

I don't think this is about filtering correctly or specifically enough, it's just that the filtering also yields a blank string in addition to what I want to filter. What I mean by that is Match 1 is what it should be, but Match 2 is just an empty string (literally characters 27-27) right at the end of Match 1's spot (first screenshot). I'd like that to go away - currently, there are twice as many 'matches' as there should be. I'd be hard-pressed to figure out why on my own. Hopefully, the screenshot explains everything that I could not make clear.

Comment: Please insert relevant code as text. Images makes it very hard to test your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use or `|` to say it must be either the username or the dash

`([a-z]{1,}\d{1,}|\-)(?=(\s\[))`

Since you have a `?` behind both groups it can also match nothing